# What can I use as stub for a file descriptor for select()

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to `select()` 2 sockets. I have a main loop and a set I'm `fd_set()` the fds into. One of the file descriptors is unknown at start, and only after I get the fd from the other socket, I know the first one, still it is important for me to have only 1 main loop and 1 `select()`.

Is it possible/good-practice to do the following:

```
a = -1;    // IS THIS RIGHT TO GIVE -1 TO SELECT?
b = known_file_descriptor;

while(1)
{
    fd_zero(set) 
    fd_set(set, a); 
    fd_set(set, b);

    select(set,read,NULL,NULL,NULL)

    if(is_Set(a))
    ...

    if(is_set(b))
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

File descriptors are just integers. I suggest you use an array of integers to store the file descriptors in, and an additional fd_number variable which stores the number of descriptors in the array. If you will only ever have 2 you can keep them in seperate variables (a and b) and keep a third variable to tell you weather to set a or not to.

```
int a, b, a_is_known=0;
b = known_file_descriptor;

while(1)
{
    fd_zero(set) 
    fd_set(set, b); 
    if (a_is_known) {
        fd_set(set, a);
    }    

        select(set,read,NULL,NULL,NULL)
    if (a_is_known){    
        if(is_Set(a))
        ...
    }
    if(is_set(b))
        ...
}
```